# modifying table row values on Angular table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a reusable table the [cellData]="row" populate each cell on the table (sample table is on the screenshot).

What I want is how to we replace the null values on the template with "---" so that instead of displaying nothing on the cell if value is empty I wanna display "---".

Is it possible to do it in `<app-table-multi-sort-cell-default [cellData]="row" [id]="column.id" [subId]="getColumnSubId(column.id)" [columnName]="column.name"></app-table-multi-sort-cell-default>` so I don't have to modify the row objects and just do it in the template. Thanks for any help.

#table-multi-sort.component.html code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of table.columns" [matColumnDef]="column.id">
      <mat-header-cell class="table-multi-sort-header" *matHeaderCellDef [mat-multi-sort-header]="column.id"> 
        <div>{{column.name}}</div> 
        <div class="sub-text">{{getColumnSubtitle(column.id)}}</div>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (click)="editRow(row)">
          <ng-container *ngIf="column.id !== 'action'; then col; else actionCol"></ng-container>
          <ng-template #col>
            <app-table-multi-sort-cell-default [cellData]="row" [id]="column.id" [subId]="getColumnSubId(column.id)" [columnName]="column.name"></app-table-multi-sort-cell-default>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #actionCol>
            <app-table-multi-sort-cell-action [rowData]="row" [actions]="getActions(column.id)" (actionClickEvent)="clickTableAction($event,row)"></app-table-multi-sort-cell-action>
          </ng-template>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUVK9.png)

#table-multi-sort-cell-default.component.html

```
<div>{{cellData[id]}}</div>
<div class="cellSubText secondary-text">{{cellData[subId]}}</div>
```

#table-multi-sort-cell-default.component.ts

```
export class TableMultiSortCellDefaultComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() cellData:any;
  @Input() id: any;
  @Input() subId:any;
  @Input() columnName: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple function for handling null values:

```
export class TableMultiSortCellDefaultComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() cellData:any;
  @Input() id: any;
  @Input() subId:any;
  @Input() columnName: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public customFunc(row: any, columnId: any) {
    row[columnId] = row[columnId] == null ? '---' : row[columnId];
    return row;
  }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<app-table-multi-sort-cell-default 
  [cellData]="customFunc(row, column.id)" 
  [id]="column.id" 
  [subId]="getColumnSubId(column.id)" 
  [columnName]="column.name">
</app-table-multi-sort-cell-default>
```

Comment: I tried Sir , but it does not work hehe

Comment: Creating and calling a custom function ↑↑↑ won't help ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9Rc1B9D , the problem is that each row is an object

Comment: @MarkRichards Well, that is easy one - add the `column.id` as second parameter and go from there - if `row` is object then you have to select the right property based on current column (`column.id`) - I have updated the answer

Comment: @MarkRichards update the `row[column.id]` if it's `null`, then return the modified `row`

Comment: how about the subId Sir ? cause as you can see here on 2nd column the 121, 111 is the subId https://imgur.com/a/n7J3t48 , I want also to replace it with --- if null

Comment: <div class="cellSubText secondary-text">{{cellData[subId]}}</div>

Comment: The same way as above - in customFunc you can check for null and modify `row[getColumnSubId(columnId)]` before returning the `row`